# SQL Server declare variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use

```
Insert into table 
    select (col_name) 
    from another
```

For example :

```
insert into table1(salary) 
    select salary 
    from table2

If (variable=700)
Begin
Insert .......
End
```

Can I declare a variable and let the value of it equals the salary

While select row number 1 , the value is the salary in row 1

while selecting row number 2 , the value of the variable is the salary in row number 2

And so on?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: your issue is resolve or not , plz let me know

Answer (score 3):

From the code provided, `@variable` is a scalar, but `SELECT` salary from `table2` will return a result set with one column, so direct assignment is not possible or it will fetch only the **last** (thanks Ken for pointing out) value from your `SELECT`.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, I think you want something like:

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT 
   (CASE WHEN salary = 700 THEN ...
     WHEN salary = ... THEN ...)
     ELSE ... END)
```

Or maybe it can be done even better, if you provide us the whole thing you are trying to do.

Comment: You are absolutely correct in your answer above though there is a minor error in your parenthetical statement in the first sentence.  A direct assignment to a scalar in a multi row result set will assign to the scalar the LAST, not the first, value.  The following quick-and-dirty query verifies this `declare @object_id int; select @object_id = object_id from sys.objects order by object_id asc; select @object_id`.  This query will return the LAST object_id not the first one.